# Developing automatic web crawler using Java

Tags: web-crawler

Hello I want to crawl multiple e-commerce web sites and get all the available products to be crawled and show in my web site. i have already developed crawler using Java but in that we have to manually crawl the web sites by giving the URL and HTML tags details and crawl the site by connecting the URL and parse the URL and get the product inside the corresponding HTML tags. i am using JSoup for that
example doc.getElementsByTagName("CRAWL"); to get the product inside the tag called "CRAWL"

But i want to fully automate the crawling. if i am searching for a product in my website then that corresponding product should crawl from the e-commerce web site automatically. if i want to crawl canon camera, crawler should do it automatically..

**IS it possible to automate the crawler? if yes please help me with how to do it.**

Comment: Starting a crawl after a user fires a query, downloading multiple product pages, extracting relevant content and then displaying that to the user would might take an impractical amount of time. Why not crawl and index every item beforehand?

Comment: i did setting up automation like crawling many number of sites at a time by running the crawler once. for that i set up some property file and read sites property from that file. but i want something like that Google does.. if i search for a product i want that product from number of sites.. when i searched, Google API is deprecated and not giving Google API to third party. so how can i do that ? is there any other search API available to get the product and i can get it as JSON format.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably better off using a products API than scraping websites and gathering content.

1. scraping is more difficult and site specific
2. scraping might not be allowed

How about some of these APIs?

[Amazon Product Advertising API](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html)

[eBay Shopping API](http://go.developer.ebay.com/developers/ebay/products/shopping-api)

[Semantics3](https://www.semantics3.com/)

[Factual API](http://factual.com/products/cpg)

(Note: I personally have not used them.)

Comment: thank you so much for the reply. i think that looks like a better solution than scrapping the site. **thank you**